# C++ namespaces: how to declare and use variables belonging to a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am debugging some C++ software, and want to declare and use a variable of a particular type in one of the .cpp files (and in its associated .h file).

I have added the code I want (using the variable I've mentioned) to the .cpp file, and this appears to be valid (i.e. no red lines under the code in Visual Studio 2010). The code I have added to the .cpp file is in the existing function, `publishData(void)`:

```
void PublisherModule::publishData(void){
    ...
    Types::ModeRecord ModeData;
    Types::ModeRecord& ModeDataPtr = ModeData;
    DataStore->getModeData(ModeDataPtr);
    ...
}
```

I have declared these variables in the .h file with:

```
using namespace Types;
...
class PublisherModule :
{
public:
    ...
    Types::ModeRecord;
    ModeRecord ModeData;
    ModeRecord *ModeDataPtr;
    ...
};
```

But I get an error on the line `Types::ModeRecord;` which says:

> Error: a class-qualified name is required

If I comment out this line, and try to build the code, I get a few different compile errors, but the first one says:

> error C2871: 'Types': a namespace with this name does not exist

But that namespace clearly does exist, since I have stated that I am using it at the top of the .h file... If I right click the namespace 'Types' in the .h file, and choose 'Go to definition', it takes me to the Types.h file, in which `namespace` is defined as follows:

```
namespace Types{
    ...
    ModeRecord{
        ...
        //lots of variables declared (not defined) here
        ...
    };
```

Anyone know why I'm getting the "class-qualified name required" error?

Comment: You forgot to give it a name: `Types::ModeRecord mr;`

Comment: I think you should just do `#include "Types.h"` where you need to use the types.

Comment: While the problematic line itself is incomplete, and the cause of one of your errors, the rest of the code you show is woefully incomplete as well. `ModeRecord` *what*? Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Comment: There's just too many things wrong with your code and too little information given to know what to suggest. What to you think the line `Types::ModeRecord;` is doing? I mean it's clearly wrong, but how can it be fixed unless it's explained what it's supposed to do. Secondly why do you declare variables in your class and then declare variables with the same names in your `publishData` method? Do you want the variables defined in your class or your method? Pick one, both is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: More missing information, which line does the error 'error C2871: 'Types': a namespace with this name does not exist' apply to? You should provide complete code, the answer to your question almost certainly lines in one of the ellipses.

Comment: This reminds me of "John leaves for NYC at 9:00 am and arrives at 12:30pm" Where did he depart from?